# Collision detection in Pacman using ACM graphics (java)

Tags: java

I have a game loop:

```
private void gameLoop() {
    boolean done = false;
    while (!done) {

        if(pacmanState == "right") {
            pac.move(20, 0);
            pause(100);
    }
        if(pacmanState == "left") {
            pac.move(-20, 0);
            pause(100);
    }
        if(pacmanState == "down") {
            pac.move(0, 20);
            pause(100);
    }
        if(pacmanState == "up") {
            pac.move(0, -20);
            pause(100);
    }

         if(pac.getBounds().intersects(b2.getBounds())) {

         if(pac.getY() <= b2.getY() - (b2.getHeight()/2)) {  //Hit was from below the brick
         pac.move(0, 0);
         }


         if(pac.getY() >= b2.getY()+ (b2.getHeight()/2)) { //Hit was from above the brick
         pac.move(0, 0);
         }


         if(pac.getX() < b2.getX()) {  //Hit was on left
         pac.move(0, 0);
         }


         if(pac.getX() > b2.getX()){  //Hit was on right
         pac.move(0, 0);
         }

         }
```

But the pacman goes right through the brick. I cannot see what is wrong with this logic.

In my previous attempts, i used a switch statement, merging the movement of the pacman and the collision detection, like so:

```
        switch (pacmanState) {
        case "left":

            pac.move(-20, 0);
            pause(100);
            if (pac.getBounds().intersects(b2.getBounds())) {
                if (pac.getX() > b2.getX()) {
                    pac.move(0, 0);

                } else {
                    pac.move(-20, 0);
                    pause(100);
                }
            }
            break;
```

But that method behaved strange, stopping only halfway through the brick, or not being able to move away from the brick after stopping [failed attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z169D.png)

Comment: There is nothing in place preventing `pac` from going through a wall. In the `if (pacmanState...` part, `pac` moves no matter what, in the following `if`-clause is checked, whether `pac` is in any wall (`b2`?), but in that case, nothing happens (`pac.move(0, 0);`). Also: It would be neat to know what `b2` is.

Answer (score 0):

In your top code snippit, it looks like you are testing for the collision after you have *already moved* pacman.  Then, if there is a collision, you move pacman zero distance, but on the next loop, the part above the collision check is going to move pacman again.

For proper collision checking, you need to test the position that pacman *would* occupy *if* it moved, and then carry out the move only if a collision would not happen.  In general, if you test *after* the move, it's already too late.